# Continue to + verb?

Tags: grammar

Why in the verb "continue to" when followed by another verb, this verb is written in its base form and translated as gerund (ending ing- in English and ando/endo in Spanish) despite the fact that it is preceded by "TO" [(continue to + verb in base form)in the writing ]= [(continue + verb in gerund) in the translation].

Comment: Differences across languages should be explored on Linguistics.SE. 'He continued to read' and 'He continued reading' are synonymous to a high degree (contrast 'He stopped to look' and 'He stopped looking'). Verbs are very idiosyncratic in the way they behave.

Comment: There's a simple answer, though. Differences in complement type, like gerund versus infinitive, are governed by the verb they are complement to. Every verb has its own rules, and you have to learn each one separately; there's no general rule. And this is true in Spanish, too -- and Spanish verbs **also** have their own individual styles, which are not the same as English verbs. That's all, really; gerund vs infinitive does not even occur in most languages, and when it does it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

In English both forms are possible.

*Continue to walk until I tell you to stop!*

*Continue walking until I tell you to stop!*

Unfortunately which to use depends on the context so I'm not sure how to give a rule. I'll think about it. Let's see if someone else gives an answer first.

---

Note that it is not "continue to" because the "to" does not belong to "continue". Instead it belongs to the following verb and indicates the infinitive form.

"***Continue to*** walk."  (incorrect)

"Continue ***to walk***.  (correct)